# Mixing user data with ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch to store listings. The user can sort by multiple fields (e.g. grossReturn, buyingPrice) etc.

Now we want to offer the option, that the user can store favorite listings.

Am storing the favorites in PostgresSQL. Then before each request I'm getting the favorites from Postgres - putting them in an array and have a scripted field like so:

```
const scripts = {
    favorite: {
      script: {
        source: 'return params.favorites.contains(params._source.id) ? 1 : 0',
        params: {
          favorites,
        },
      },
    },
  };
```

Now I also want to sort by this field and this is the problem:

```
const getSortParams = (sortBy, scripts) => {
  const sort = {};

  if (sortBy) {
    const fieldName = sortBy.split(',')[0];
    const sortOrder = sortBy.split(',')[1];
    if (fieldName === 'favorite') {
      sort._script = {
        type: 'number',
        script: scripts[fieldName].script,
        order: sortOrder,
      };
    } else {
      sort[fieldName] = {
        order: sortOrder,
      };
    }
  }
  return sort;
};
```

It is very very slow - sorting taking roughly 3s. It makes sense since everything needs to be calculated.

My question would be -> what is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Add a property to your listing definition class that would indicate whether it's a favourite or not (true, false).
Since its per user basis, maybe add an array property for your user model that would store an array of favourite listing ids.

Comment: Hmm. So you mean storing an array of userIds within the listing? Is that a proper approach?

Comment: There is no "proper" approach as there are multiple ways to skin a cat. In my books, you're doing double the work by maintaining two data stores, hence the suggestion of migrating either the listings or users or at least tie them by id, i.e. store favourite listing ids liked by the user.

Comment: I'm doing the second approach: Storing ids that are favorited. Then before every call I get all favoriteIds and pack them in a scripted field. But that is - as said - not very performant on sorting :) This is why I want to know a better approach

Comment: If understood you correctly you were trying to sort on result set returned by the script, wheres now you would be sorting on a value that is actually stored in the document. Big difference.

Comment: Maybe then I have not understood your answer correctly. I agree if I store a value its a huge difference. Can you elaborate this a little more in your answer how you would do that? :)